# National Bike Month (US)!

Tags: discussion, bike-to-work-month, bike-to-work-day

[image: National Bike Month Flyer]

(content stolen from [our blog post](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/national-bike-month-and-bike-to-work-week/)).

In the US, May is [National Bike Month](http://www.bikeleague.org/programs/bikemonth/), and next week (May 14-18) is **National Bike to Work Week**. This is an awesome opportunity to challenge yourself to commute by bike more often, and with the weather getting warmer, it's the perfect time to get back into the habit of using your bike to get around.

Individual communities have bike challenges, with prizes sponsored by local bike advocacy groups, cycling shops, and bike groups. The League of American Bicyclists has a webpage where you can [look up official Bike Month events](http://www.bikeleague.org/programs/bikemonth/events.php) in your community. Not all events are listed on this site, so you should also do a web search for *bike to work <city name>* and see what you can find. For example, Oregon has the [Walk and Bike Month Challenge](http://www.walknbike.org/), New York City has [Bike Month NYC](http://www.nycgovparks.org/events/bike_month), San Francisco Bay Area has a [Bike to Work Day](http://www.youcanbikethere.com/), and dozens of other communities across the US have their own programs.

**Not every city's Bike to Work events are on the "official" dates, so make sure to check for local events right away so you don't miss out!**

As you get geared up for spring commuting, don't forget to [ask Bicycles Stack Exchange](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) when you have questions about setting up your bike!

Comment: See also: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/609/ideas-for-events-to-promote-bicycles-se-at/612#612

Comment: And: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/696/76

Comment: And: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/617/bike-to-work-day-week-month